# Any android developer here who is using nokia xl?

Tags: android, nokia, nokiax

Any NOKIA XL android developer here? I can't run a simple app on my NOKIA XL, but it's running on emulator.

When I plug in any android cell phone, the eclipse detects it when I say it to run the android app. But it's not detecting my NOKIA XL.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Mention reason for down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the instructions for using the device : [device-setup](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/device-setup.html), specifically do check Driver installation via Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd to read whole documentation, but now I'm enjoying running my apps on my nokia xl through andriod studio.